# Laravel object based datatable

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

Retrieving data in my Laravel 8 controller as follows:

```
$projects_data = Project::with('group')->get(['id','group_id'])->toArray();
return response()->json($projects_data);
```

Gives the following result - a JSON format, with an array of **objects** (might be the problem):
[image: ajax call response]

Yet, the client side datatable response is:

> "DataTables warning: table id=records-table - Requested unknown
> parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this
> error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/4"](http://datatables.net/tn/4%22)

HTML code is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered data-table" id="records-table">
                           <thead>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Id</th>
                                   <th>group_id</th>
                               </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tbody>
                           </tbody>
                       </table>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#records-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                ajax: {
                       url : 'projects/data',
                       dataSrc: "",
                       dataType: "json",
                       columns:[
                           {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                           {data: 'group_id', name: 'group_id'},
                       ],
                   },
            });
        });
```

I'd be grateful for some help here. Again, I suspect that the table expects a JSON format data, consists an array of arrays, and the Laravel response gives an array of objects.

Tried to change the js code, removing the processing attribute, removed the `dataSrc` which fixed a prior error, yet the error persists.

.

Comment: Check the "Network" tab of your browser's devtools. Is the request made?

Comment: Your response does not match the json structure the js plugin expect, like for example the data property

Comment: @Lk77 is right. You should return something like `['data' => response()->json($projects_data)]`

Comment: 1. Request is made. 2. How do I return an array or arrays from Laravel controller, JSONed ?